# Chef's policy groups and environments

Tags: chef-infra

It is clear the intention of using a policy group per environment (Like dev, staging or production, like [they do here](https://www.chef.io/blog/policyfiles-a-guided-tour)). However when it comes to handle some attributes which are environment-related, like names or seeds addresses, it is quite tricky to handle using policy files in comparison with old role/environment layout.

Currently I am using an extra layer of attribute namespace with the name of the policy group, for example:

```
default['foo']['development']['bar'] = 'zaz'
default['foo']['production']['bar'] = 'zaz'
```

And later inside the recipe address them like this:

```
default['foo'][node.policy_group]['bar']
```

Where `node.policy_group` will resolve to `development` or `production`, depending on the machine `policy group` has assigned.

My main concern here is that I have to carry around on each `Policyfile` a plethora of attributes which are not related to the environment where it is going to be deployed, for instance if I set a ElasticSearch cluster, I should carry the list of master nodes of all environments on the `Policyfile`.

Is there a better way to manage environment attributes using `Policyfile`? I am ***really*** condemned to carry one gazillion of attributes on each `Policyfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same discussion this week an the "Ask me Anything" session at Config Managament Camp.

An employee of *Chef Software Inc.* (IIRC Thom May) said that they are indeed thinking about adding the possibility to specify some environment-specific attributes, as this seems to be a frequently requested feature.

Until then, you might want to retrieve such data maybe from a data bag (which follows a certain naming convention).

While I'm not a user of `Policyfile`s (yet), I'm using a [similar approach](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-base/blob/024faa893689b7c78ae5f3705d3627abcca76983/README.md#datacenter---production-configuration) ([implementation](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-base/blob/024faa893689b7c78ae5f3705d3627abcca76983/recipes/_datacenter.rb#L33-L78)) to load data center specific attributes and merge them with those from the current role cookbook. In my understanding, this should help you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The poise-hoist cookbook might help a little bit but roughly speaking yes you need to have a big blog of attributes. You can avoid duplicating them in every policy using some `instance_eval` tricks as shown in https://yolover.poise.io/. More generally for things like "which ES server to use" you might want to consider using a dedicated service discovery tool like Consul or Eureka.

Answer (score 1):

The poise-host approach has been incorporated into chef infra directly now for several years now:

https://docs.chef.io/release_notes_client/#policyfile-hoisting

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, and what I recommend to my customers is to use an "Environment `data bag`", this is outlined here for traditional Chef Environments: https://docs.chef.io/data_bags/#environments

You can take the same logic and apply it to a `policy_group` (the logical replacement for environments) by doing the following:

```
{
  "id": "some_data_bag_item",
  "production" : {
    # Hash with all your data here
  },
  "testing" : {
    # Hash with all your data here
  }
}
```

When using the data bag in a recipe, that data can be accessed from a recipe using code similar to:

```
data_bag_item[node.policy_group]['some_other_key']
```

This is utilizing the `poise-hoist` functionality that was added into Chef Infra Client in version `14.0`: https://docs.chef.io/release_notes_client/#policyfile-hoisting.